# TCPDF I can't get the html from another page like index.php?something=something

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am struggling to create a pdf file with tcpdf from a dynamically generated page.

My problem is that I've got a logging session and when accessing the file it gets only the credentials if you're not logged in.

So my bit for collecting the html is:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.domain.com/subdir/index.php?something=ref');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

So what I've got after running it, is 'HTTP Error 401: - Unauthorised'.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working with PDF using TCPDF where in curl CURLOPT_USERAGENT was TCPDF like below.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'TCPDF');
```

I just commented this line and try to generate pdf and it worked.

I know this is not a proper way but it worked for me.